# how to os.path.join uneven lists element-wise

Tags: python, os.path

say i have

```
folders = [['folder1/subfold'],['folder2/subfold/subsubfold']]
clas = [['class1'], ['class2', 'class3','class4']]
```

how can i join paths of the classes to their respective folders? Desired:

```
['folder1/subfold/class1',
'folder2/subfold/subsubfold/class2',
'folder2/subfold/subsubfold/class3',
'folder2/subfold/subsubfold/class4']
```

the following seems to only work when the lists are of the same dimensions: `[os.path.join(*i, j) for i,j in zip(folders, clas)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is nested for loops

```
[os.path.join(*i, j) for i, names in zip(folders,clas) for j in names]
```

Comment: thanks, this works ! just had to add ```os.path.join(*i,j)```